# How do I call an object an object from a .fxml file in my controller file?

Tags: java, image, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am making a stopwatch program and I want to set a photo for rotation. The problem is, is that I dont know how to call the photo in the controller file. It just tells me that it cannot find symbol.

Heres the photo I want to call from my .fxml file

```
 <ImageView fx:id="hand">
     <image>
        <Image url="@hand.png"/>
     </image>
  </ImageView>
```

And heres where I call it in my controller file, but I get an error.

```
@FXML
 private void updateStopwatch(){
    elapsedTime++;
    Integer rotation = elapsedTime * 6;
    hand.setRotate(rotation);      


 }
```

Thanks for the help in advance. The error I get is the following :

```
hand.setRotate(rotation); 
^^^^
Cannot find symbol hand
```

Comment: It needs to be `fx:id="hand"`

Comment: You fxml file also needs to refer to your controller class. `fx:controller="pathToController"`

Comment: @user2651804 in which file? I just tried changing it in both and it didnt work

Comment: it has that line @user2651804

Comment: I don't understand? It has what line? I will post an answer.

Comment: It refers to my controller class... I just didnt post that code. But I updated my code and put "fx:id = "hand"" in the .fxml file and it still doesnt work.

Comment: @johndouhjyel yeah but this is not magic, `hand` is not defined in your Java code you need to get it somehow. I've never used JavaFX with FXML files, I prefer writing the whole code myself, but I'm sure this is really well documented, so you don't need us

Comment: exactly @dici. I am wondering how I get the hand id from the other file? :(

Comment: @johndouhjyel it is **necessarily** in the doc

Comment: `root` has a `.getController()` method which will give you access to the method. This kind of practice of changing your question entirely is **NOT OK**

Comment: Sorry I didnt know. I wont do it again!!!! how do I use this ?like root.getController(updateStopwatch);

Comment: the getController class returns your controller. Like any other class, to invoke it's method you do: `.updateStopwatch()` --> `root.getController.updateStopwatch()`

Comment: So i put this right after the action event part of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have given the fxml object you want to inject into your controller the correct property `fx:id="hand"` you need to declare that id as a property in your controller class.

```
public class MyController {
    @FXML private ImageView hand;

    private void updateStopwatch(){
        elapsedTime++;
        Integer rotation = elapsedTime * 6;
        hand.setRotate(rotation);      
    }
}
```

In your fxml file you must refer to the controller(MyController) by adding this attribute in root element:

```
fx:controller="some.package.MyController"
```

your fxml file may only refer to one controller.

Comment: What do you mean by classname?

Comment: Whatever Object that hand should be.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have one more question if you can answer it. But its not the same topic as this although it is the same program. The question is.... How do I call a function from my controller file in my main .java file? I can update my main question with my code

Comment: You shouldn't change your current question to a new one. It defeats the purpose of the SO forum. Since your question is a pretty broad one, look elsewhere for the answer (before you post a new question).

Comment: Also, there is no "correct" way to do that, so you're not looking at a 'simple' fix. I would say that the best solution is to not do that at all.

Comment: So I shouldnt call a controller function in my main file/?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not and expert on code design. But at the very least I was wrong in saying there wasn't a 'simple' way to do it.